# Binding TextCell in TableView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, tableview

I have passed details to the next `Form` with `strings` and `integers` and I stored them inside the `Class's` constructor, now how can I bind the values in the constructor (parameterized values) to the `TextCell` inside the `TableView`.

initially, this is how I launch another form.

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginSalesDetails(Usnmae, AgentNumber, AgentName, AgentPhone, AgentEmail, Agentrating));
```

This is my Class Code :

```
public LoginSalesDetails(string Username, string AgentNo, string AgentName, string AgentPhone, string AgentEmail, int AgentRating)
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            accountname_label.Text = AgentName;
            agent_no_label.Text = AgentNo;
            rating_label.Text = "" + AgentRating;
            mobileno_label.Text = AgentPhone;
            email_label.Text = AgentEmail;

            Name_A(AgentName);


        //  DisplayAlert("Alert ", ""+AgentName, "OK");
        }




        public string Name_A(string a) 
        {


            return a;
        }
```

Then, this is XAML code which consists of the `TableView` and `TexCells`.

```
<TableView Intent="Form">
            <TableView.Root>
                <TableSection Title="Agent Sales Details">
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Number" Detail="{Binding Name_A}" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Rating " Detail="4" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Phone " Detail="0474774747475" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Email " Detail="huxy@gmail.com" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableView.Root>
        </TableView>
```

**EDIT**

My Class.cs code :

```
public partial class LoginSalesDetails : ContentPage
    {
        public string Name_A { get; set; }
        public string Email_A { get; set;}
        public string Phone_A { get; set;}
        public string Rating_A { get; set;}
        public string No_A { get; set;}

        public LoginSalesDetails(string Username, string AgentNo, string AgentName, string AgentPhone, string AgentEmail, int AgentRating)
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            accountname_label.Text = AgentName;
            agent_no_label.Text = AgentNo;
            rating_label.Text = "" + AgentRating;
            mobileno_label.Text = AgentPhone;
            email_label.Text = AgentEmail;

            Name_A = AgentName;
            Email_A = AgentEmail;
            Phone_A = AgentPhone;
            Rating_A = ""+ AgentRating;



            //  DisplayAlert("Alert ", ""+AgentName, "OK");
        }


    }
```

My XAML code :

```
<TableView Intent="Form">
            <TableView.Root>
                <TableSection Title="Agent Sales Details">
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Number" Detail="{Binding Name_A}" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Rating " Detail="{Binding Email_A}" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Phone " Detail="{Binding Phone_A}" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Email " Detail="huxy@gmail.com" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableView.Root>
        </TableView>
```

Comment: You can't bind to a method, it has to be a public property

Comment: how is that done

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: Man you are a Genius , let me first read this doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , i have another alternative give each of the TextCell an id then just simply assign the id with the string data:

As below

XAML:

```
<TableView Intent="Form">
            <TableView.Root>
                <TableSection Title="Agent Sales Details">
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Number"  x:Name="agentNumber_txtcell" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Rating "  x:Name="agentRating_txtcell" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Phone "  x:Name="agentPhone_txtcell" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Email "  x:Name="agentEmail_txtcell" />
                </TableSection>
            </TableView.Root>
        </TableView>
```

Then simply in your C# class just assign the ID (x:Name) to the strings:

```
public LoginSalesDetails(string Username, string AgentNo, string AgentName, string AgentPhone, string AgentEmail, int AgentRating)
{
    InitializeComponent();



    agentNumber_txtcell.Detail= AgentNo;
    agentRating_txtcell.Detail= ""+AgentRating;
    agentPhone_txtcell.Detail= "" + AgentPhone;
    agentEmail_txtcell.Detail= AgentEmail;





//  DisplayAlert("Alert ", ""+AgentName, "OK");
}
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You are now trying to bind to a method, that is not possible. This should always be done to a public property. For instance, change your code like this:

```
public string Name_A { get; set; }

public LoginSalesDetails(string Username, string AgentNo, string AgentName, string AgentPhone, string AgentEmail, int AgentRating)
{
    InitializeComponent();



    accountname_label.Text = AgentName;
    agent_no_label.Text = AgentNo;
    rating_label.Text = "" + AgentRating;
    mobileno_label.Text = AgentPhone;
    email_label.Text = AgentEmail;

    Name_A = AgentName;


//  DisplayAlert("Alert ", ""+AgentName, "OK");
}
```

Notice that I removed the method, and added the `Name_A` as a property.

Also, if you haven't done so, you need to set the `BindingContext` of the page that holds your `TableView` to the instance of the `LoginSalesDetails` object.

Comment: Hey , i did it , but you know what its not binding the text is just blank

Comment: Please specify what 'it' is? What did you change in your code? And what does it look like now?

Comment: Do you have any code that sets the `BindingContext`?

Comment: Then please read the last lines of my answer. You need to set the BindingContext. The page does not magically know what object to use for its bindings.

Comment: Please show me how i can do that setting the Binding Context